# Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts in VB.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm trying to connect to MySQL from the  other PC as I run my program it says that Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts

```
Dim strConn As String = "Server=192.168.xx.xx;Database=mydatabase;Uid=root;Pwd=mypassword;Port=3306"

Dim con As New MySqlConnection(strConn)
Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand("select * from station_tbl", con)

Dim adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
Dim dt As New DataTable()
Dim td As New DataTable()

adapter.Fill(dt)
adapter.Fill(td)

ComboBoxStationOrigin.DataSource = dt
ComboBoxStationDest.DataSource = td

ComboBoxStationOrigin.DisplayMember = "station_name"
ComboBoxStationDest.DisplayMember = "station_name"
ComboBoxStationOrigin.ValueMember = "station_id"
ComboBoxStationDest.ValueMember = "station_id"
```

Comment: Are the two pc on the same subnet? Did you open the port 3306 on the pc where MySql is installed? Just to exclude firewall issues try to temporarily disable the firewall on the pc where MySql is installed

Comment: Hello Steve. The firewall on the PC is already disable. And nothing happens. Thank you sir

Comment: Can you connect from MySQL Workbench on the remote PC?  I would try to get it working outside of code first.